# submitting a form on click of link in cherrypy

Tags: python, cherrypy

Below is my cherrypy code:

```
class MyApp:
    def link_details(self, **params):
        pass
    link_details.exposed=True
```

The below is my html code:

```
<form name="form1">
<input type="text" name="username"> <a href="link_details">Click here</a>
</form>
```

The page gets redirected, but I am not able to access the form request parameters. I want the form to be submitted to the link_details method on the click of a link in the html page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're not submitting the form, you're just linking to a different page.

The easiest way to submit a form is by using a submit button:

```
<form id="form1" action="/link_details" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If you want to submit the form with your `<a>` tag:

```
<form id="form1" action="/link_details" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <!-- you can omit the "return false;" part, but since we don't use a "href" attribute on the anchor it does not matter -->
    <a onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();return false;" target="_self">Submit</a>
</form>
```

For more information on a form's attributes (such as `action` and `method`) please visit https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: Hi, I am aware that I am just linking. But I want the form to be submitted on the click of that link. Some languages have something called a commandlink through which a form submission happens. This is usually done using javascript onclick=submit(). I just wanted to see if there is any other alternative.